# Flyback Regulator and Flyback Transformer

Tags: transformer

I wish to generate electric sparks for some fun. I found out that Flyback Transformer are well suited for my purpose.

[image]

But I do have a simple 220/25V Transformer. I do not want to do winding for converting it to a flyback(also I do not know how to do it). I saw a circuit Online called Flyback Regulator:

[image]

Can I use this circuit instead to do my work? Can I just plug in an oscillating circuit at place of a PM generator and produce sparks?

Comment: If it's a 50Hz or 60 Hz transformer, it is unlikely to work well at the operating frequencies of those circuits.

Comment: If your objective is fun, then please break this down to a list of techy requirements.

Comment: A flyback transmformer and an 'ordinary' transformer are rather different beasts, each optimised by their permeability to do their own job well, at the expense of the other. Ordinary transformers have high, ideally infinite, permeability to minimise energy stored with current. Flyback transformers have low permeability to maximise energy storage. Using an ordinary transformer as a flyback will be a disappointing experience.